# Plotting periodic discontinuous functions in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, math-mode

How do I represent periodic functions in LaTeX that also have discontinuities? I tried the `pgfplots` package. But it seems like the package does not support discontinuous functions.

[image]

Comment: You can definitely produce your figure with pgfplots, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/544697/194703.

Comment: The graph you show is continuous as it can be traced without removing the pencil from the paper. If you mean for the vertical line to be gone (so it's a true function) you just need to adjust your graph using an [open circle or closed circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169638/simple-characteristic-function-or-step-function-in-pgfplots) like is shown at the link.

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some solutions if you are using tabular data for the plot

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis equal,
            axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,
            enlargelimits=true,
            legend style={at={(0,1.05)},anchor=south west},
        ]
        % If you want the vertical line at x=0
        \addplot+ table{
                -3 1
                -2 1
                -1 0
                0 0
                0 1
                1 1
                2 0
                3 0
            };
        % If you want the vertical line at x=0
        \addplot+ table{
                -3 1
                -2 1
                -1 0
                0 0

                0 1
                1 1
                2 0
                3 0
            };
        % If you want the vertical line at x=0
        \addplot+[dashed,unbounded coords=jump] table{
                -3 1
                -2 1
                -1 0
                0 0
                0 nan
                0 1
                1 1
                2 0
                3 0
            };
            \legend{default,empty line in table, nan in table + "unbounded coords=jump"}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]